# Trouble accessing DBContext with Scoped IHostedService

Tags: c#, dbcontext, asp.net-core-hosted-services

I am trying to create a scheduled task that executes a Sql command. The actual scheduled process works fine, however my dbcontext has an issue where it can't actually access the database.

It will get a context, with all of the appropriate tables, but any action on the Tables throws an `InvalidOperationException`. When trying to examine any of the table elements in debug mode they also all say `InvalidOperationException` with a red `X` as the icon.

I have also tried sending the command through a `MediatR` command and handler but with the same errors. Every attempt at changing the code has resulted in same error with no deviation.

This is my first attempt at creating background services, for reference I was following a tutorial from
https://thinkrethink.net/2018/02/21/asp-net-core-background-processing/

Startup.cs

```
            // truncated
            services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>();
            services.AddSingleton<IHostedService, Daily_Task>();
```

Background Service

```
namespace MyApi.ScheduledTasks
{
    public abstract class BackgroundService : IHostedService
    {
        private Task _executingTask;
        private readonly CancellationTokenSource tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

        public virtual Task StartAsync(CancellationToken token)
        {
            _executingTask = ExecuteAsync(tokenSource.Token);

            return _executingTask.IsCompleted ? _executingTask : Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        public virtual async Task StopAsync(CancellationToken token)
        {
            if (_executingTask == null)
                return;

            try
            {
                tokenSource.Cancel();
            }
            finally
            {
                await Task.WhenAny(_executingTask, Task.Delay(Timeout.Infinite, token));
            }
        }

        protected virtual async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken token)
        {
            do
                await Process();
            while (!token.IsCancellationRequested);
        }

        protected abstract Task Process();
    }
}
```

Scoped Processor

```
namespace MyApi.ScheduledTasks
{
    public abstract class ScopedProcessor: BackgroundService
    {
        private readonly IServiceScopeFactory _scopeFactory;

        public ScopedProcessor(IServiceScopeFactory scopeFactory)
        {
            _scopeFactory = scopeFactory;
        }

        protected override async Task Process()
        {
            using (var scope = _scopeFactory.CreateScope())
            {
                await ProcessInScope(scope.ServiceProvider);
            }
        }

        public abstract Task ProcessInScope(IServiceProvider provider);
    }
}
```

Task to be scheduled

```
namespace MyApi.ScheduledTasks
{
    public class Daily_Task : ScopedProcessor
    {
        private DateTime Start => DateTime.Now;

        private DateTime NextTask { get; private set; }

        public Daily_Task(IServiceScopeFactory scopeFactory) : base(scopeFactory) 
        {
            NextTask = SetNextRun(Start);
        }

        // currently doing minutes for testing
        private DateTime SetNextRun(DateTime date) => date.AddMinutes(1);

        public override async Task ProcessInScope(IServiceProvider provider)
        {
            try
            {
                using (var context = provider.GetRequiredService<MyDbContext>())
                {
                    // even this causes an error
                    var data = context.MyTable.Any();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Log.Error(e);
            }
            await Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken token)
        {
            do
            {
                var now = DateTime.Now;
                if (now > NextTask)
                {
                    await Process();
                    NextTask = SetNextRun(now);
                }
            }
            while (!token.IsCancellationRequested);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding DB context as a singleton or scoped service as a test to see if it would work?  Also, consider taking a look at https://www.hangfire.io/.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily get confused learning how to do background services because there are tutorials about how to do it, and then .NET has added and changed the best practice during the development of dotnetcore that invalidates tutorials. There *is* now a BackgroundService base class you can implement, and it should be added to your DI container using AddHostedService. It's been in Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection for a little while now. If you use that instead it will greatly simplify what you're having to do to add the background service.

**Quick start about implementing the BackgroundService:**

Only override ExecuteAsync. The host will wait for it to return so if you have a long running background task (or perpetual background task) then you want to return a task rather than wait for it to complete from ExecuteAsync (ex: use Task.Run). When the app is triggered to shutdown the cancellation token passed to ExecuteAsync will be cancelled and you have a few seconds to shutdown gracefully before the process exits. :P No scope is created for a hosted service by default so you will need to inject the IServiceProvider which you already know how to do.

**Ref:** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: I did implement the provided base class, which does simplify things a good deal as you mentioned. Unfortunately the problem with the database contexts is persisting. Still helpful for other background services though.